# Pass externally defined variable to JUnit @ValueSource annotation in a @ParameterizedTest

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit5

I have an array of strings that I would like to use for multiple unit tests. In an effort to de-duplicate my code and to minimize the number of changes I would need to make to my test parameters in the future, I have tried defining a variable within my JUnit test class and then re-using this variable as the input parameter for each of my `@ValueSource` annotations. Is this even possible or am I overlooking a simple mistake?

```java
private static final String[] myParameters = {"a", "b", "c"};

// This fails with the message that `myParameters` isn't a recognized symbol, probably because it's not a valid Element for @ValueSource
@ParameterizedTest
@ValueSource(myParameters)
public void myTest(String param) {
  // doesn't compile
}

// This fails with the message that "incompatible types: String[] cannot be converted to String"
@ParameterizedTest
@ValueSource(strings = myParameters)
public void myTest(String param) {
  // doesn't compile
}

// This works fine, but I would need to duplicate the values of `strings` for each test
@ParameterizedTest
@ValueSource(strings = {"a", "b", "c"})
public void myTest(String param) {
  // works fine, but its duplicative in terms of the @ValueSource parameter
}
```

References:

- [Annotation Type ValueSource](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.7.1/api/org.junit.jupiter.params/org/junit/jupiter/params/provider/ValueSource.html)
- [JUnit GitHub](https://github.com/jashburn8020/junit-5-user-guide#valuesource)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use a `@MethodSource` to wrap your constant:

```java
private static final String[] myParameters = {"a", "b", "c"};

static List<String> myParameters() {
    return Arrays.asList(myParameters);
}

@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("myParameters")
public void myTestWithMethodSource(String param) {
    System.out.println(param);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can achieve this with `@ValueSource`, but it can be done with `@MethodSource` and `DynamicTests` for sure:

```java
@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("myParameters")
public void myTest(String param) {
    System.out.println(param);

}

Stream<String> myParameters() {
    return Stream.of("a", "b", "c");
}
```

Alternatively, this is how you'd do it with Dynamic tests. It is a cool feature of junit5 that allows you to dynamically create unit tests:

```
static Stream<String> myParameters() {
    return Stream.of("a", "b", "c");
}

@TestFactory
Stream<DynamicTest> myTests() {
    return myParameters()
        .map(p -> DynamicTest.dynamicTest(
             "testing for: " + p, 
              () -> myTest(p)
        ));
}

void myTest(String param) {
    System.out.println(param);
    assertEquals(1, param.length());
}
```

if you find this interesting, read more about it here:  https://medium.com/javarevisited/streamline-your-testing-workflow-with-junit-5-dynamic-tests-66787740f39c?sk=b10eacd4e6f6b85c51f194b240555895

Comment: Dynamic tests come with a few disadvantages. Most importantly they do not follow Jupiter's standard lifecycle (eg BeforeEach, AfterEach) whereas parameterized tests do. Moreover, you'll have to come up with your own naming mechanism; in paramterized tests you can use Jupiter's standard display name policies and generators.